# google gwt JsArrayInteger (JavaScriptObject) use via JSNI

Tags: gwt, collections

I'm relatively new to gwt and I have a problem using JsArrayInteger. Here is my code:

```
  package com.google.gwt.sample.stockwatcher.client;    
  public class StockWatcher implements EntryPoint {
      JsArrayInteger a;
      public void onModuleLoad() {
          a = (JsArrayInteger) JsArrayInteger.createArray(); 
          a.push(1);
          a.push(2);
          a.push(4);
          a.push(5);
          test();
      }
      public static native void test() /*-{
          var p = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
          var q = this.@com.google.gwt.sample.stockwatcher.client.StockWatcher::a;
          alert(q);
          alert(p);
      }-*/;
    }
```

The result is 'undefined' and [1,2,3,4,5,6] instead of [1,2,3,4,5] and [1,2,3,4,5,6]. I want to use the field a and work on that array (pass it to a third party library).

The tutorial http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html didn't explain how to use the default JavaScriptObjetcs. Does somebody find the error?

Best regards,

Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  public static native void test() /*-{
      var p = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
      var q = this.@com.google.gwt.sample.stockwatcher.client.StockWatcher::a;
      alert(q);
      alert(p);
  }-*/;
```

Note that this method is `static`, but you are referring to `this`. Either pass in an instance and use that instead of `this`, or change the method to not be `static`.

Comment: How stupid of me... I though about a complicated problem... Thank you very much!

Comment: If only the JSNI code could tell us that `this` didn't make sense... but that isn't how JS works. And that's why many people use GWT in the first place.